# Startup.cs - The path in 'value' must start with '/'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, openid-connect

I have created a new .NET Core MVC application in Visual Studio 2017 and enabled multi-tenant authentication. 
I've completed the configuration (ClientId, Authority, etc) but when I debug the application there is an exception in the Startup.cs, specifically the `app.useOpenIdConnectAuthentication` method.

The exception given is

> System.ArgumentException: The path in 'value' must start with '/'.

I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to C# and .NET Core, so I'm not sure whether I'm missing something obvious. The main sticking point is what the debugger is referring to with the parameter 'value' as I can't see any mention of it in the code. There are no changes beyond the default template generated by visual studio, other than adding the configuration items to the appsettings.json.

Comment: It would be helpful if you include your startup.cs code in the question.  `value` is the name of the *parameter*, not the name of something from your code.

Comment: Do you have something like LoginPath or similar path configured in auth config? Those paths/route should start with `/`

Comment: Probably an invalid URL in one of the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions properties. As #Amy says, you need to post the code.

Comment: Thanks all, managed to figure it out in the end. All the documentation suggests CallbackPath should be 'signin-oidc' without a slash, but changing it to '/signin-oidc' seems to have resolved it.

Comment: FYI. If I have the following condition: context.Request.Path == "login.html" then an exception is thrown.  However, if I do: context.Request.Path == "/login.html" then an exception is not thrown.  I was just playing with app.Run(async (context) => { ... put conditions here ... } and noticed question when I wondered what was going on.

Answer (score 7):

As there is no code in the question, so I will try to make a general answer as possible.
This exception appears when you use this overload `PathString.FromUriComponent(string)` and the string does not start with the `/` character

so,for example, the following code will throw an exception :

```
PathString.FromUriComponent("controllerName/actionName"); // throw exception
```

and to fix the previous exception you can write it like this

```
PathString.FromUriComponent("/controllerName/actionName"); // working, but as relative path
```

and of course, this will be a relative path.

In case you wanted to use an absolute path, (and not start your string with `/`), then you must use another overload of this method which takes `Uri` object as a parameter instead of `string`

here is an example

```
// use an absolute path
PathString.FromUriComponent(new Uri("https://localhost:8000/controller/action/"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I also get the same exception, but with another method `UseExceptionHandler`:

The error was:

> ArgumentException: The path in 'value' must start with '/'. Nombre del parámetro: value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString..ctor(string value) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.UseExceptionHandler(IApplicationBuilder app, string errorHandlingPath)

Fixed by replacing

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("Home/Error");
```

with

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
```

notice the addition of the `/` char at the beginning of the string.

Comment: This code is for handling exceptions in general, this does not solve the problem

Comment: My point is as same as your answer, using the relative path to solve the issue :)

Comment: I think I got your idea now, but the answer itself does not explain that idea exactly. you mentioned a lot of details which is not related to the exception itself. I will edit your answer to make it focus on the issue itself.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks @HakanFıstık