# Error The path in 'value' must start with '/' in ASP.NET Core 2 in application deploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, deployment, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to deploy an asp net core 2 application, all seems to be ok, I'm using deploy Files option in VS2017, to my path inetpub\wwwroot\App1 folder, I add the application.
I browse to the path http://localhost:8088/App1/Home/Index/
then I see :

> ArgumentException: The path in 'value' must start with '/'.
>        Nombre del parámetro: value
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString..ctor(string value)
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.UseExceptionHandler(IApplicationBuilder
>   app, string errorHandlingPath)
>       OCIndicadoresOperativoClientes.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder
>   app, IHostingEnvironment env) in Startup.cs
>       System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISSetupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   builder)
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

below you can see the code of Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace App1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(25);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            });

            services.AddAuthenticationCore();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("App1/Home/Error");

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Home",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Shippers",
                    template: "{controller=ControllerB}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "ControllerB",
                    defaults: new { controller = "ControllerB", action = "Index" });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

also, I will include the webconfig details:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\App1.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Do you see any error? i would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Based from stack trace, the error occurred in this line:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("App1/Home/Error");
```

Currently you're using this overload of [`UseExceptionHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.exceptionhandlerextensions.useexceptionhandler?view=aspnetcore-2.1) which expects URL path:

```
public static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder UseExceptionHandler (
              this Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder app, 
              string errorHandlingPath);
```

Note that `errorHandlingPath` parameter requires proper URL format because it will be used to call [`PathString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.pathstring.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.1) constructor, hence you should add slash on the beginning of URL:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/App1/Home/Error");
```

Similar issue: [Startup.cs - The path in 'value' must start with '/'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41834645/startup-cs-the-path-in-value-must-start-with)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. It was coming because the exception handling path is expected to start with a "/"

The error was:

> ArgumentException: The path in 'value' must start with '/'. Nombre del parámetro: value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString..ctor(string value) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.UseExceptionHandler(IApplicationBuilder app, string errorHandlingPath)

Fixed by replacing

```
  app.UseExceptionHandler("Home/Error");
```

with

```
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
```

Also you can try deploying with

```
  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

and find the error if any.